# splitting string and putting each output into a unique variable in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to split a string simply by the spaces between each word within the string.
I then want to put these different parts of the string into separate variables. How do I go about doing this? 
I have the following:

`strOperatingSystem = “Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ”`

```
strVendor = “”
strEdition = “”
strTitle = “”
strVersion = “”
```

I want the result to be.

```
strVendor = “Microsoft”
strEdition = “Windows”
strTitle = “Professional”
strVersion = “7”
```

`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5) the string at spaces and assign the individual fields of the resulting array to the respective variables.

```
strOperatingSystem = "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"

arr = Split(strOperatingSystem)

strVendor  = arr(0)
strEdition = arr(1)
strTitle   = arr(3)
strVersion = arr(2)
```

Comment: While this might anser the question, please also provide a short explanation on what your code does and how it solves the initial problem.

Comment: I assumed something this basic would not require further explanation. Oh, well.

Comment: Your answer was flagged for low quality and since we strive for quality content, some explanation and a link to the documentation are always welcome. Additionally, as an experiences SO user, you can be a good role model for new members.

Comment: Oh, well, indeed.